# Substring() fails - need to cast result as string instead of default double

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-8.1

I thought substring is easy until I tried:

```
# extract from a webpage with regex into $mmdd the value like 08/09
Write-Host $mmdd
08/09
$mmdd.Substring(0,2)
```

Then I get:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Double] does not contain a method named 'Substring'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $test.Substring(0,2)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

```
> $test.Substring(3)
```

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Double] does not contain a method named 'Substring'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $test.Substring(3)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

How do I cast the variable `$mmdd` to string so I can use `Substring()` on it?

I suspect I have to do something to the following:

```
$page | Select-String -Pattern $mmddyyyyRgx -AllMatches |
    % { $_.Matches } |
    % { $_.Value } |
    Select-String -Pattern $mmddRgx -AllMatches |
    % { $_.Matches } |
    % { $_.Value } -Outvariable mmdd
```

Since $mmdd gave me:

```
0.888888888888889
```

it's a double balue, casting like below will not work as expected:

```
[string]$mmdd.Substring(0,2)
```

it will give me
    0.
instead of
    08

Comment: Does "Write-Host $mmdd" really return "08/09"? Since it says that it's a double that shouldn't be the case. $mmdd.ToString().Substring(0,2) should work either way. When you store the value into $mmdd it should also work to declare it as a string [string]$mmdd = x.

Comment: no. returns something like 0.888888...9. it treats 08/09 as division result!

I got around that by extracting with regex more than just "08/09" and ended up with a collection; on which I use [0] index and .Substring to get what I want.

quite a few juggles to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

Just call the `ToString()` method on `$mmdd` so you can use `SubString()`:

```
$mmdd.ToString().SubString(0,2)
```

However, maybe you tell us about your actual problem since this could be a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: thx @Martin Brandl for reply. The way I extracted earlier, $mmdd was already a double value. I got around it with a regex that gives more than "08/09" to prevent auto convert from string to numeric type. I did end up with a collection though. so I jump through another hurdle by using [0] index before substring.

what I after was: 1. parse the html from a webpage for the file to download, the date and it's version 2. so I can log and subsequently compare before download. dnlod will be scheduled to run roughly every 2 hour but ideally can off by +/- up to 15 minutes 3. log the dnlod